# Google Store downloads Gmail

Tags: google-play-store, gmail, google

How do I use Gmail as backup for my Samsung Galaxy 6? Whenever I sign into Gmail it downloads all my email! Should I just set up a dummy account that is used only for that purpose? Or will it continue to download the email regardless. Thanks in advance.

I've disabled and deleted the email account twice but if I try to go into Google store or set up the backup here comes the email.

Answer (score 0):

just made an account for this answer.  Not sure how it would be on your s6 because of touchwiz but it should help you out.  settings>accounts>google>(Pick the account you want to back your stuff up on)>deselect email and stuff and enable backup.
:)